# Python function works for scalars but not for vectors and give me the error " only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math

I am new to python and have some back ground with matlab.
I am trying to write a function for the Gaussian kernel with 0 mean.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def GaussainKernel(x,sigma):
    xx = np.array(x)
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2*math.pi*sigma**2))*math.exp(-(xx*xx)/(2*sigma**2))
```

This works if pass scalars for sigma and x, for instance:

```
GaussainKernel(1, 1)
```

gives me the answer:

```
0.24197072451914337
```

Now if I want to pass a vector for x such as:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2])
GaussainKernel(x, 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

This has to be due to the the term `x*x`or `x**2`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math.exp` is a Python function and does not take vectors as input. Replace it with `np.exp` and everything will work as intended.

Also, you might want to replace `math.pi` with `np.pi` to get rid of one import.